# Excel return a list of stringe where 'TRUE'

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Ok so I have couple of cells listing warnings:

```
     A          B         C
1    Warning1   TRUE
2    Warning2   FALSE
3    Warning3   TRUE
```

Now I want to return list of warnings that are set to `TRUE`. Desired Output: `Warning1 Warning3`

I know that I could use `CHOOSE` for this where I would treat `TRUE/FALSE` as `1/0` and read list of warnings as a binary nubmer( for `choose`'s first parameter), but my list is quite long.

Also I tried following formula, but it returned only the first value:

`{=CONCATENATE(IF(B1:B3=TRUE,A1:A3,""))}`

Maybe someone can tweek this to work.

So does my approach gets me close is there another/better way of doing this??

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10229869/657668). For your case, you should use `=CCARRAY(IF($B$1:$B$3,$A$1:$A$3)," "))` entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: I was actaully hoping to get this done without VBA but your soultion does seem right. thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just use a series of IFs like: =IF(B1,A1,"")&IF(B2,A2,"")&(IF(B3,A3,"")&...  ?

Comment: Yes as I noted in the question my list is quite long, and if it wasn't for the length I would have totaly used your solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to concatenate arrays without VBA. The concatenate function accepts only single values. For example, you can't do this:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1:A3)
```

So the problem is not the use of arrays, but the design of the built-in concatenate function.

From what I've heard, there are add-ins that can do this. MOREFUNC is one, it has a function called MCONCAT(). I'm not familiar with that add-in, but you could give it a try.